# How to insert data into database using EditText and then save data into database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

i am new in android development, so i am trying but i can't do the insertion data into database using Edit Text and then save the data into data using Button in android.
so someone please help me out, i am just a beginner that's why please write a sample tutorial/program on it.

advanced thank you,
arnob

ok here is my one of my class activities and an xml file i am attaching -

one of my activity class names "Registration.java" and it contains -

```
package com.ggit.trip.caster;

  public class Registration extends AppBaseActivity {

private Button submit3;
private Button exit3;

DatePicker d;
Dialog dialog;
public TextView date;
private ImageView cal;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.registration);

    registerBaseActivityReceiver();

    submit3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    exit3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    cal = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);

    submit3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    CostManagement.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    cal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog = new Dialog(Registration.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.date);
        //dialog.setTitle("Set Date");
            dialog.setCancelable(true);

            Button ok = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            Button cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button2);

            d = (DatePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);

            ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int day = d.getDayOfMonth();
                    int month = d.getMonth();
                    int year = d.getYear();

            String curDate = "" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

                    Log.d("date", "" + curDate);

                    date.setText(curDate);
                    date.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    cal.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }           
            });     

            dialog.show();
        }
    });

    exit3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            closeAllActivities();
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();
    unRegisterBaseActivityReceiver();
}
```

}

for this class activities i have made a layout for this registration named "registration.xml" .

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@drawable/sea_01" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="User Name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="  insert your name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Passord"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="E-mail"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="  insert your email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Phone Number"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText3"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="   contact number"
    android:inputType="phone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="Gender"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText4"
    android:text="Male"
     />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:text="Female"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="Location"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="   place you living" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="Birthday"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView6"
    android:src="@drawable/calendar" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:background="@drawable/gloss_nine_patch"
    android:text="Submit" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gloss_nine_patch"
    android:text="Exit" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="User Registration"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="12dp" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Now please someone please full fill this "Registration.java" class using database query and after writing all the information when i ll click 'submit' button it will save into database then go to other activities.

thanking you all 
please help me now

Comment: Show the code you wrote so far. Also EditText is UI component. It got nothing to do with the database. Your question needs clarification (or you should follow some Android DB tutorials first)

Comment: Welcome in Stackoverflow. Please post your effort/code you tried so far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135404/how-to-store-multiline-edittext-into-sqlitedatabase-android   is similar to what you need. A simple google search will turn up hundreds of examples. As the others have said show what you have done so far, and where the specific issue is. Otherwise go to rent a coder and pay someone to write it for you.

Answer (score 4):

Arnob you can find very good tutorials at following links, ...

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

I hope it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a notepad SDK sample provided with the Android SDK platforms that does all of this. You could go through that. Additionally, there are hundreds of tutorials on using databases with Android apps freely available.

Comment: thank you by the way here i give u an one of my class activities.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like

```
public class AndroidSQLiteTutorialActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    EditText getTextFromThis = (EditText) findViewById(getTextFromThis);
    EditText putTextHere = (EditText) findViewById(putTextHere);
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
      b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          String s = getTextFromHere.getText().toString(); //getting confused where you get/put the data.
          db.add(new StringObjectThingy(s)); //say you have a SQLiteDB with StringObjectThingies
          putTextHere.setText(s);
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

This better?

Comment: thank you but actually i need a sample of using database where i can text something into edit box then save it into database.